# SyntaxError in UsersController#index

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

```
- if flash.present?
- flash.each do |type, message|
%strong #{type.titleize}:
=message
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@mina HAML is sensitive for blank spaces. so the code you want inside the `if` block must be 1 tab indented in next line like:

```
- if flash.present?
  - flash.each do |type, message| 
    %strong 
      = type.titleize + ":" 
    = message
```

`-` sign is used for ruby code to evaluate etc
`=` sign is used to show the output of code on your browser.

for more information see [haml documentation](http://haml.info/tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote this way?

```
- if flash.present?
  - flash.each do |type, message| 
    %strong 
      = type.titleize + ":" 
    = message
```